# Script to Colour Characters in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

How can I automate a find & replace function to change the font colour of all suit symbols sheet wide?

I write bridge articles (card game), and I need to automate this formatting constantly:

Find all "♣" and color the text green (#00b700). Find all "♦" and color the text orange (#ff8100). Find all "♥" and color the text red (#ff0000). Find all "♠" and color the text blue (#0000ff).

Another person asked the same question for google docs, and produced a script.

I have tried to adapt it to google sheets, but am getting

"TypeError: body.editAsText is not a function" errors

Here is the script I am using:

```
function onOpen() {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
       .createMenu('Utilities')
       .addItem('Auto-Replace', 'replaceSuits')
       .addToUi(); 
};   

function replaceSuits() {
   var body = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   
   var text = body.editAsText();
  
   var found = body.findText("♥");
   while (found) {
     var elem = found.getElement();
     if (found.isPartial()) {
       var start = found.getStartOffset();
       var end = found.getEndOffsetInclusive();
       elem.setForegroundColor(start, end, "#ff0000");
     }
     else {
       elem.setForegroundColor("#ff0000");
     }
     found = body.findText("♥", found);   }
     found = body.findText("♦");   while (found) {
     var elem = found.getElement();
     if (found.isPartial()) {
       var start = found.getStartOffset();
       var end = found.getEndOffsetInclusive();
       elem.setForegroundColor(start, end, "#ff8100");
     }
     else {
       elem.setForegroundColor("##ff8100");
     }
     found = body.findText("♦", found);
   }
   found = body.findText("♣");
   while (found) {
     var elem = found.getElement();
     if (found.isPartial()) {
       var start = found.getStartOffset();
       var end = found.getEndOffsetInclusive();
       elem.setForegroundColor(start, end, "#00b700");
     }
     else {
       elem.setForegroundColor("#00b700");
     }
     found = body.findText("♣", found);
   }
   found = body.findText("♠");
   while (found) {
     var elem = found.getElement();
     if (found.isPartial()) {
       var start = found.getStartOffset();
       var end = found.getEndOffsetInclusive();
       elem.setForegroundColor(start, end, "#0000ff");
     }
     else {
       elem.setForegroundColor("#0000ff");
     }
     found = body.findText("♠", found);
   } 
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you quote uses classes that are only relevant to the Google Docs text editor. To do the same in Google Sheets, use the [RichTextValueBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder) class. The script below will format text automatically as you edit the spreadsheet.

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
'use strict';

/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user opens the
* spreadsheet.
*
* Adds a menu item to highlight a phrase.
*
* @param {Object} e The onOpen() event object.
*/
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Highlight')
    .addItem('Highlight text in selected cells', 'formatPhrasesInText')
    .addToUi();
  if (!e) console.log(`New "Highlight" menu was added in the spreadsheet's menu bar.`);
}


/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) throw new Error('The onEdit(e) function is not designed to run in the script editor window.');
  formatPhrasesInText(e.range);
}


/**
* Applies rich text formats to currently selected cells.
* Text that matches regex is formatted using the methods listed.
* For a regex overview, see:
* https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html
* For available formatting methods and their parameters, see:
* https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-style-builder
*/
function formatPhrasesInText(range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()) {
  const specs = [
    { regex: /bbb/gi, format: { setForegroundColor: 'red', setBold: true, } },
    { regex: /iii/gi, format: { setForegroundColor: 'blue', setItalic: true, } },
    { regex: /uuu/gi, format: { setFontSize: 16, setUnderline: true, } },
    { regex: /♥/gi, format: { setForegroundColor: 'red', } },
    { regex: /♦/gi, format: { setForegroundColor: 'orange', } },
    { regex: /♣/gi, format: { setForegroundColor: 'green', } },
    { regex: /♠/gi, format: { setForegroundColor: 'blue', } },
  ];
  formatText_(range, specs);
}


/**
* Applies rich text formats to text in a range.
* Formats substrings that match a regex, each substring separately.
* Handles multiple occurrences of each phrase in each cell.
* Skips formula cells. Mutates specs. Retains existing formats.
*
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Range} range The range to format.
* @param {Object[]} specs An array of objects { {RegExp} regex, [{SpreadsheetApp.TextStyleBuilder['methodName']: parameter}] }
* @return {SpreadsheetApp.Range} The same range, for chaining.
*/
function formatText_(range, specs) {
  // version 1.6, written by --Hyde, 12 February 2024
  //  - see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/167300/269219
  const richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues();
  const values = range.getValues();
  const formulas = range.getFormulas();
  const result = richTextValues.map((row, r) => row.map((value, c) => {
    if (!value || typeof values[r][c] !== 'string' || formulas[r][c]) return;
    const text = value.getText();
    const richText = value.copy();
    let match;
    specs.forEach(spec => {
      while (match = spec.regex.exec(text)) {
        if (!spec.textStyle) {
          const textStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle();
          for (const [method, parameter] of Object.entries(spec.format)) textStyle[method](parameter);
          spec.textStyle = textStyle.build();
        }
        richText.setTextStyle(match.index, match.index + match[0].length, spec.textStyle);
      }
    });
    return richText.build();
  }));
  return range.setRichTextValues(result);
}
```