# Google Sheets Conditional Format to highlight specific pieces of text within a cell

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Is it possible to condition format so that sheets will format specific pieces of text within a cell instead of applying formatting to the entire cell. Is this an option in sheets yet?

e.g If cell contains "ABCD Data" and I want just the "ABCD" part to color in red.

Google search brings up regular formatting, or formatting for partial text match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) rules can only format cells "in full" and cannot format individual words within cells.

To format partial text within cells automatically, use a script. See the [formatText](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/167300/269219) script for sample code.